# Typescript With Axios Response

Tags: typescript, axios

Working with Typescript while making an API call with `axios` and have come across a nested data scenario.

Although I believe to have it typed correctly, I keep receiving a Typescript error stating `Unsafe return on an any typed value` and `Unsafe member access .data on an any value` for the `return response.data.data[0];` line of my `try/catch`. Can someone provide some clarity around why my types aren't working as I "think" they are?

```
export interface Source {
  curr: string;
  uuid: string;
  rate: string;
}

export interface Response {
  data: {
    data: Array<Source>;
  };
}

async function getSource({ curr, uuid, rate }: Source): Promise<AxiosResponse<Response>> {
  const requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'get',
    url: '/url',
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios(requestConfig);
    return response.data.data[0];
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('error');
  }
}
```

Comment: `axios(requestConfig)` returns `AxiosPromise<any>`, so `response.data` is of type `any`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some re-work, I landed on using `axios.get` and was able to get it all worked out.

```
export interface Args {
  curr: string;
  uuid: string;
  rate: string;
}

export interface Response {
  curr: string;
  uuid: string;
  rate: {
    curr: string;
    type: string;
  }
} 

async function getSource({ curr, uuid, rate }: Args): Promise<AxiosResponse<Response>['data']> {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get<{ data: Response[] }>('/url');
    return response.data.data[0];
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('error');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what exactly you are looking for but this might help you. Playground link: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4AcD2IMoDeAUMmcsACYBcyAjANzEC%20xxoksiKAggB7AcGdNjwEAPCNz4IAPhLlkIOAFsItAOQBlALIaWbBGLDIAbnAA2yALzI4GAJ4gEyABQBKWgAUoOFcAl%20QWFMaQkpMTlZG2iFciN8EyhMWiChCJlJUMjo2zjFMmU1am09UnJWRWSwAFcoEGRkjCZmIA)

```
async function getSource({ curr, uuid, rate }: Source): Promise<AxiosResponse<Response>> {
      const requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        method: 'get',
        url: '/url',
      };
    
      try {
        const response: AxiosResponse<Response> = await axios(requestConfig); //funtion expects <AxiosResponse<Response>> as return.
        return response;
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('error');
      }
    }
```